# Baking or cake supply store in Prague not closed at Christmas

Tags: public-holidays, prague

I'll be in Prague at the end of this month (24th, 29-31 Dec) and I would like to buy some bakeware products such as Silpat silicon mat and stand mixer and cookie sheet.

Is there an area popular for its baking or cake supply stores that are open over the Christmas period?

Comment: Any large household items store (maybe in a mall) should have what you are looking for and be open at least on 29+30 Dec.

Comment: I read this more as an ‘is something open that fits my needs?’ question and am thus voting to leave open.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no area in Prague famous for cooking supplies, as most of that stuff is made abroad anyway. If you need to buy some around Christmas, visit any large hypermarket (e.g. the [Tesco near Andel](http://itesco.cz/prodejny/obchody-tesco/hypermarket-praha-novy-smichov) metro station) - they will be open until **12:00** on the **24th** and then during regular hours on the **27th and onward**.

Source: I live in Prague.

Answer (score 2):

Been there, done that... I didn't find any professional baking supplies in Albert, Tesco or other similar hypermarkets. What I found was a bakeware store in Palladium center and Tescoma store in Černý Most Prague Metro station.